# Dev Environment Tests Not 100% Compatible with Staging/Production in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

We use a bunch of specific apps/APIs that (unfortunately) differ quite a bit from dev to staging/production. We use tests and continuous integration at each stage, but in dev, the tests fail annoyingly (throwing dialogs, etc - thanks Windows for the 64-bit notification!). I hate to write custom code, but are there some best practices for how to allow a subset of testing in ruby/rails - or for patching out specific tests when you're running on Windows?

Some specific situations that:

- Identify.exe does not support 64-bit Windows and throws a dialog.
- Sethostname is not supported, and throws an error (at least it's command line).

Comment: Is your dev environment different from staging or production, in terms of the operating system, o/s version, database type / version or anything else ?  Just wondering why you only get these problems in dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mock out the code to decouple the dependency on the other apps. Use [Mocha](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/) to create the mocks dynamically.